# Docker deployment using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-docker

I am using Jenkins for my CCID stuff. I have two servers one is server1 and another is server2. In server1 I have installed Jenkins (Docker is not installed) and in server2 I have installed Docker.

I have made use of `docker.build` command for my docker build process in my JenkinsFile and run it in server1, but it throws 'docker command not found', because there is no Docker installed in server1. And the code I have used is as below:

```java
stage 'Build Docker image'
node {
  def image = docker.build('/sampleApp:2.1')
}
```

I need to run these Docker commands on server2.

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins has the concept of *Labels*, which you can assign to nodes (master and slaves). You should now give the node(s) that have `docker` installed a label, e.g., `docker`.

This can be done through *Manage Jenkins* > *Manage Nodes* and then click the gear icon on the right to configure your *server2*:

[image: slave configuration]

In your pipeline, you can supply the label to the `node` step, in order to run on a node having the particular label:

```java
node('docker') {
  def image = docker.build('/sampleApp:2.1')
}
```

Comment: `node('server2') { ... }` would also suffice, although I think it is better practice to label nodes, because it is scalable and not bound to a node

Comment: Btw. if anybody knows a piece of documentation (besides the one contained in Jenkins), I'd add a link - but I couldn't find anything on the web.